# jinja if statement is not working. I don't know how to fix it

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I really need help!
The code does not display different values. if the code finds a join item it should display a link, if it does not find a join item it should display a form. Else: display some text.

html:

```
{%- if join -%}

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <center>
        <a href="/clubs/{{ club.id }}/add_post" style="text-decoration:none; font-size:18px; color:white; padding:10px 20px 10px 20px; background:#134401;">Add Post +</a>
        </center>
{%- elif not join -%}
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
                <form action="/clubs/{{ club.id }}" method="POST">
            <center>
            <input type="submit" value="Join" style="width:20%; padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px; background:#1d2d0d; color:white; font-size:20px">
            </center>
        </form>
{%- else -%}
<h1>nope</h1>
{%- endif -%}
```

function:

```
@application.route('/clubs/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def viewClub(id):
    post = Post.query.filter_by(clubId=id)
    club = Club.query.get_or_404(id)
    join = Join.query.filter_by(clubId=id, userId=current_user.id)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = club.name
        user = current_user.username
        userId = current_user.id
        clubId = club.id
        createClub = Join(name=name, clubId=clubId, user=user, userId=userId)
        db.session.add(createClub)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render_template('viewClub.html', club=club, post=post, join=join)
```

Comment: The only two possibilities are `if join` and `not join`.  What condition are you expecting the `else` to cover?

Comment: Also, the syntax of those `if` statements is odd.  It should be `{% %}`.  Why are you using `{%- -%}`?

Comment: @JohnGordon The minus sign removes the [whitespace](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#whitespace-control).

Answer (score 0):

Your database query doesn't return a result of the query, it returns the query itself. This is always true when checked.

You forgot to add a function like `.first()` or `.all()` to the query.

```
join = Join.query.filter_by(clubId=id, userId=current_user.id).first()
```